# Unable to Fetch All Files and Folders in a given folder in Microsoft One Drive using MS Graph API C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I need to fetch all files and folders in a given folder (SGIM) of a One Drive user account using MS Graph API.

I wrote a program that works without logging any exception, but the files/folder count reported is less than actual files/folder count in the given folder.

#Actual: (Files/Folders count in /SGIM folder path in root)
Files: 62,683
Folder: 13,598

#Reported by my Program: (Files/Folders count in /SGIM folder path in root)
Files: 25,887
Folder: 13,576

Can someone please help me fix the issue in code.
Please see my code Snippet below:

```
private HttpClient oneDriveHttpClient;
        public string AccessToken = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25j........................";
        public string RefreshToken = "...............................";
        List<Item> allitems = new List<Item>();

        public MainProgram()
        {
            string requestUri = "/v1.0/users/d7ddb19e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx/drive/root:/SGIM:/children";
            this.oneDriveHttpClient = new HttpClient()
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com")
            };

            await GetOneDriveFolderView(requestUri);
        }

       public async Task GetOneDriveFolderView(string requestUri)
        {
            string errorlog = Global.ErrorLog;
            ConcurrentQueue<string> pendingitems = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
            List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

            try
            {
                pendingitems.Enqueue(requestUri);
         
                do
                {
                    items = new List<Item>();

                    try
                    {
                        pendingitems.TryDequeue(out requestUri);
                        
                        items = await GetOneDriveChildItems(requestUri);
                        if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
                        {
                            var folders = items.Where(s => s != null && s.Folder != null).ToList();

                            if (folders != null && folders.Count > 0)
                            {
                                foreach (var folder in folders)
                                {
                                    string requestUri2 = "";
                                    if (requestUri.EndsWith("/root/children"))
                                    {
                                        requestUri2 = requestUri.Replace(":/children", "").Replace("/children", "") + ":/" + Uri.EscapeUriString(folder.Name) + ":/children";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        requestUri2 = requestUri.Replace(":/children", "").Replace("/children", "") + "/" + Uri.EscapeUriString(folder.Name) + ":/children";
                                    }
                                    
                                    pendingitems.Enqueue(requestUri2);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(errorlog, "\r\nDateTime:" + DateTime.Now.ToString() +
                                "\r\nRequestUri" + requestUri  + "\r\n" + ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);                            
                    }
                }
                while (pendingitems.Count > 0);

                long totalcount = allitems.Count();
                long folderscount = allitems.Where(s => s.Folder != null).Count();
                long filescount = allitems.Where(s => s.File != null).Count();

                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(errorlog, "\r\nDateTime:" + DateTime.Now.ToString() +
                    "\r\n\r\nFolders Count: " + folderscount +
                    "\r\nFiles Count: " + filescount +
                    "\r\nTotal Count: " + totalcount);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(errorlog, "\r\nDateTime:" + DateTime.Now.ToString() +
                        "\r\n" + ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);             
            }            
        }


        public async Task<List<Item>> GetOneDriveChildItems(string requestUri)
        {
            List<Item> files = null;
            List<Item> tmpitems = new List<Item>();
            
            try
            {
                OneDriveResponse<Item[]> oneDriveResponse = null;

                do
                {
                    oneDriveResponse = null;
                    int retry = 3;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= retry; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                           oneDriveResponse = await this.GetOneDriveItemSet<Item[]>(requestUri).ConfigureAwait(false);
                           break;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {                         
                            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(errorlog, "\r\nDateTime:" + DateTime.Now.ToString() +
                            "\r\nRetry Attempt " + i.ToString() + " - FilesResource.ListRequest Execute For RequestURI " + requestUri + "\r\n" + ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
                         
                            Thread.Sleep(3000 * i);
                            oneDriveResponse = null;
                        }

                        if (i > retry)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (oneDriveResponse != null)
                    {
                        requestUri = oneDriveResponse.NextLink;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        requestUri = null;
                    }

                    if (oneDriveResponse != null && oneDriveResponse.Value != null)
                    {
                        files = oneDriveResponse.Value.ToList();

                        if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
                        {                     
                            allitems.AddRange(files);
                            tmpitems.AddRange(files);                            
                        }                        
                    }
                } while (requestUri != null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(errorlog, "\r\nDateTime:" + DateTime.Now.ToString() +
                "\r\n" + ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);                
            }

            return tmpitems;
        }
        
        
        private async Task<OneDriveResponse<T>> GetOneDriveItemSet<T>(string requestUri)
        {   
             try
             {           
                 // Send the request to OneDrive and get the response.
                 var response = await this.SendOneDriveRequest(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri)).ConfigureAwait(false);

                 // Request was successful. Read the content returned.
                 string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                 return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OneDriveResponse<T>>(content);
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 throw ex;
             }
        }
        
        private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendOneDriveRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {            
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", this.AccessToken);
            var response = await this.oneDriveHttpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

            // Check for token refresh
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                var authresult = new AuthenticationResult();
                authresult.Code = this.RefreshToken;
                TokenResponse tokenresponse = await GetAccessToken3(authresult);
                this.AccessToken = tokenresponse.AccessToken;
                this.RefreshToken = tokenresponse.RefreshToken;

                var newRequest = await request.Clone().ConfigureAwait(false);               
                newRequest.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", this.AccessToken);
                response.Dispose();
                response = await this.oneDriveHttpClient.SendAsync(newRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);               
            }       

             // Any failures (including those from re-issuing after a refresh) will ne handled here
             if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
             {
                 throw OneDriveHttpException.FromResponse(response);
             }

             return response;
        }
        
        
        public class OneDriveResponse<T>
        {
            [JsonProperty("@odata.context")]
            public string Context { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("@odata.nextLink")]
            public string NextLink { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("@odata.deltaLink")]
            public string DeltaLink { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("@delta.token")]
            public string DeltaToken { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("value")]
            public T Value { get; set; }

            public OneDriveResponse()
            {
            }

            public OneDriveResponse(T value)
            {
                this.Value = value;
            }
        }
        
        
    public class Item
    {       
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("createdBy")]
        public IdentitySet CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("createdDateTime")]
        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("cTag")]
        public string CTag { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("eTag")]
        public string ETag { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("file")]
        public FileFacet File { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fileSystemInfo")]
        public FileSystemInfoFacet FileSystemInfo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("folder")]
        public FolderFacet Folder { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lastModifiedBy")]
        public IdentitySet LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lastModifiedDateTime")]
        public DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("parentReference")]
        public ItemReference ParentReference { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("size")]
        public long Size { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("deleted")]
        public DeletedFacet Deleted { get; set; }

       public string PathDisplay { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class FileFacet
    {
        [JsonProperty("mimeType")]
        public string MimeType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("hashes")]
        public HashesFacet Hashes { get; set; }
    }


   public class FolderFacet
   {
      [JsonProperty("childCount")]
      public long ChildCount { get; set; }
   }
```

Thanks,
Gagan

Comment: Try listing both in alphabetical order then check if the missing files match a specific pattern

Comment: If your folder is shared check if the files that are missing belong to other users. Probably the API call `/v1.0/users/{user-id}/drive/root:/SGIM./children` only return files that belong to the user identified by `user-id`.  Try to retrieve the drive id and item id of the folder and than call `/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/children`